# Correct way to create hotspot programmatically in devices with Cyanogenmod (6.0+)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cyanogenmod, hotspot

```
public static boolean isApOn(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    try {
        Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("isWifiApEnabled");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        return (Boolean) method.invoke(wifimanager);
    }
    catch (Throwable ignored) {}
    return false;
}
public static boolean configApState(Context context) {
    WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiConfiguration wificonfiguration = null;
    try {
        // if WiFi is on, turn it off
        if(isApOn(context)) {
            wifimanager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }
        //Change Name of the Created Hotspot
        try {
            Method getConfigMethod = wifimanager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration");
            WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = (WifiConfiguration) getConfigMethod.invoke(wifimanager);                
            wifiConfig.SSID = "abcde123";
            wifiConfig.preSharedKey = "password123";                wifiConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
            wifiConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            wifiConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
            wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);

            Method setWifiApMethod = wifimanager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
            boolean apstatus = (Boolean) setWifiApMethod.invoke(wifimanager, wifiConfig, true);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Method method = wifimanager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        method.invoke(wifimanager, wificonfiguration, !isApOn(context));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when i run this code, hotspot is created but when clients turn to connect to it, it stucks on "Obtaining Ip Address" loop. Tested on CM13, CM14 for many devices. 
Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Could you give some more explanation what you are doing and what you are expecting? Reading plain code without an idea of what it should do is tough.

Comment: When i try to connect it from the client side, its showing "WifiConfigStore(857): SSID temp disabled for "abcde123"-WPA_PSK had autoJoinStatus=0 self added false ephemeral false"

Comment: Maybe some problem with DHCP service, don't you have to start one programmaticaly ? Or does the wifimanager class turn it on automatically ?

Comment: No, you should edit your question to do this. Make it easy for people to answer. Also, consider http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask